# as3 - loop over all text fields?

Tags: forms, actionscript-3, post

I have a form in as3 flash with textfields and radio buttons with their "instance name" all set consecutively such as: 
field_1 
field_2 
field_3 
...etc

Is there an easy way in AS3 code to loop over all those fields and get their values in an array? Ideally I'd like a simply loop to get the values (so I can add in a simple popup if a value is missing) and then with the filled array simply post it using URLRequest.

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered using a datagrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a for statement. I've also used a multi-dimensional array to store the instance names, and the text that they contain. I like to use the variable _path to define the scope of my code.

```
var _path = this;
var text_ar:Array = new Array(['instance_1',''],['instance_2',''],['instance_3','']);    //instance name, instance text.

for(var i=0; i<ar.length; i++)
{
     text_ar[i][1] = _path[text_ar[i][0]].text
}

trace( text_ar[1][1] ); //Traces the text that's entered in instance_1.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a way that's a little less work and more maintainable (if the amount of text can change in the future or you need to reuse the code on other forms or don't want to bother with instance names), then you could do something like the code below.

Keep in mind this assumes all your text fields are children of the same parent and is in the scope of that parent (so on a frame in the timeline that holds all your text fields)

```
function validateTextFields(){
    var tmpTf:TextField;
    var i:int = numChildren;
    while(i--){ //iterate through all the display objects on this timeline
        tmpTf = getChildAt(i) as TextField;
        if(tmpTf){
            //now that you have the textfield, you can check for an appropriate value, or send the value to a server, or store it in an array etc.

            //check if the value is blank, if so set the background to red
            if(tmpTf.text == ""){
                tmpTf.background = true;
                tmpTf.backgroundColor = 0xFF0000;
            }else{
                tmpTf.background = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```